# ECS with ALB, web and application Server

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, nexus, amazon-elb, amazon-ecs

I have an Application Load Balancer setup with internet facing and ECS Container service setup with Auto Scaling Group with 2 private subnets in AWS. I would like to install Nexus with Nginx. What would be the best strategy so I can fully utilize all these services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you want to deploy Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of Nexus. If so the following reference architecture from AWS should help:

https://github.com/awslabs/ecs-nginx-reverse-proxy/tree/master/reverse-proxy

It shows how to create a task definition that has two tasks linked to each other, such that a nginx reverse proxy container can sit in front of your application and send traffic to it.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This is something I wanted to do but I was wondering if I will be able to customize Nginx configuration file to add CA certificate for HTTPS or link more server containers later on. The link you provided does not have anything about HTTPS and my ECS with Auto Scaling Group would create another Nginx task as soon as I customize the Nginx configuration.  In addition, all the recently changed configuration in Nginx has been lost after I made changed in Nginx.

Comment: @AlwaysALearner Ideally you want your containers to be immutable.  You can't change a running container and expect the new state to persist.  If you want to add changes to nginx, create your own Dockerfile (which can simply be copied from the official nginx repo), make the changes there then rebuild and deploy your new image to ECS.

Comment: Yep, if you want to change the nginx.conf you rebuild the container so now you have two versions of it: one version that has the old, original nginx.conf and one version that has the new settings. Then you would update the task definition in Amazon ECS so that ECS rolls out your updates by replacing all the old tasks with new tasks that are using your new docker container.

Comment: Hi @LukePeterson and nathanpeck,  Thank you so much for the clarification. I was totally confused before but now I understand why I having issue deploying nginx container. Thanks again.

Comment: But `nginx` has problem of `no resolver`. it can't refer to docker's `link` option. See this [ha-proxy reverse-proxy repository](https://github.com/gnokoheat/ecs-reverse-proxy)